# Hyphenation in title

Tags: discussion

See [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344818/holiday-present-ation-vs-content-contest).

Is the hyphen in title intentional? (Strong) perhaps, yes.

Why was it put there? To attract attention? Or to convey some kind
of connotation?

Comment: I think in this case it is only a word pun, a joke...

Comment: @CarLaTeX Thanks. Do I get a bit more explanation about the pun? I am still missing it somehow.

Comment: I'm not native English-speaking, I'm sure someone in the Community will answer soon. We have also linguists here :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX My first language is not English as well.

Comment: As you can see, our linguist has already answered :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hyphen is intentional, since it draws attention to the word 'present', something that is commonly associated with Christmas, in cultures that celebrate it.